# databricks asset bundles wheel task error

Tags: databricks, databricks-cli, databricks-asset-bundle

I wanted to use the Databricks cli to deploy a python wheel in Databricks. However after running `databricks bundle deploy` I am getting an error:

```
Error: INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)
```

I tried it with the template project from the cli too (`databricks bundle init`). I am getting the same error.

Databricks CLI version: 0.205.0

What should I change in the project to be able to work with python wheels?

I basically followed the steps in this description: https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/tutorial-bundles.html

Comment: Can you post your `.yaml` definition?

Comment: I am using the `yaml` from the template project (`databricks bundle init`)

Comment: open github issue on datarbicks/cli project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the solution for the problem.

For some reason the cli uses python with the `python3` command. However in my Windows distribution python could be used only with the `python` command (I assume this is the normal way to work with python in windows).

The solution for me was to clone the `python.exe` and rename it to `python3.exe`. After that the `databricks bundle deploy` worked as expected.